# Minecraft on mobile - safest way for my kids to play with friends who live out of state

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My kids used to play Minecraft with their friends over LAN with tablets, but we moved.  I can set them up with xBox live accounts, but ideally I would like to replicate the single world over LAN where they are playing in a world with just these friends. The goal being to prevent them from interacting with unvetted strangers online.  While I could potentially try to setup  server, I am the only one in the household that could troubleshoot it, and I don't need the headache of a home server not working when I am not available.

I see there are a lot of similar questions here, but the answers I see are assuming that all players are on a PC, and tend to discuss downloading a popular VPN exe.  My kids and their friends are on tablets a mix of iOS and Android.

Thoughts on how to create these limited worlds to play over the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Mojang offers private Minecraft servers for mobile and console Minecraft through the Realms service, which costs a monthly fee (7.99$ U.S.D. as of Jan. 2020). This includes server maintenance.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I will explore that option.  I'd also be interested in free or one time cost options, so anybody reading these responses please fell free to add additional ideas.

Comment: @Mike Those only exist as extremely suspicious services which you should probably not use or as the one you already found: Hosting it yourself. Which isn't technically free, because of electricity and wear on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have an extra pc or something you can download an app or go to a website that allows you to create a free server. Aternos is a website that will run a server but it won't stay live 24/7
https://aternos.org
But you will need to enter the port address and other stuff.[image]

Just make sure that you don't host the server your self as the services have a much safer server and you could end up with a ddos attack